# play m3u with vlc on raspberry pi using ssh

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, pulseaudio, vlc

I would like to play m3u with vlc on raspberry pi using ssh (I don't have any screen to connect to the pi).
I tried the following answer:
[Program run in SSH accessing pulseaudio on the machine where it runs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193208/program-run-in-ssh-accessing-pulseaudio-on-the-machine-where-it-runs)
But it didn't helped: I still get "PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused"
Thank You

Comment: I guess raspebby is in server mode, so fetching nautilus PID will be of no help.

Comment: exactly, i listed processus with ps -x and I chose an other processus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Find a way..
I starded vlc with a ssh -X session. Then I selected ALSA audio device instead of pulseaudio and I saved the configuration.

then I launched "cvlc http://mystream.m3u &". Finally I ctrl+D and closed the window. Sound works perfectly

Comment: now I'm trying to do it with a .sh file .