# Almost every CLI music player doesn't work (in an SSH terminal)

Tags: command-line, audio, pulseaudio, music

Goal: Play music on a server, preferably using cmus, using SSH for player control.

First try: `cmus`
I run `cmus` in a terminal, literally nothing happens. It just loads (i guess). Tried `cmus -vvvvv` - Also just loads. Tried [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/2m043g/cmus_wont_load/) and [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/3cwqcp/cmus_error_opening_audio_device_no_such_file_or/) - No changes to the issue. **But:** running it from a physical terminal on the computer works! (Both starting cmus, and playing audio successfully)

Second try: `MOC`
Running `mocp` opens it up, I can add files too. When trying to play a song, this message appears: `can't open audio: device or resource busy MOC` - No possible solution found.

Third try: `mp3blaster`
It starts. I can add files. It doesn't play: `Failed to open sound device`
Tried several suggestions (very outdated) from google, nothing helped. The one that seemed to help many others with this was `padsc mp3blaster` - But again, no help for me.

I am using ALSA with PulseAudio. Audio itself works fine. `play` or `mplayer` both work fine, but they don't offer libraries and playlists. <del>Both work fine over SSH too.</del>

I'm really clueless to what to do here since cmus doesn't print anything <del>and `mplayer` works fine</del>. I checked `alsamixer` and nothing is muted or disabled. There's only one single soundcard.

Not trying to have a broad suggest-me-something question here, I just added the other players since it might help find the issue, but the question aims to focus on getting `cmus` to work.

I've tried `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus cmus` too (found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193208/program-run-in-ssh-accessing-pulseaudio-on-the-machine-where-it-runs)), same result.

**Edit: TO BE CLEAR:** The music is on the machine I SSH into and I want to play the music **locally** from the machine, **controlling** the CLI music player via SSH. Sorry for the confusion. I'm not trying to stream audio over SSH. I just want to use `cmus` in an SSH Terminal to play music that already is on the server I'm connecting to.

Edit: `mplayer` doesn't work anymore either, it used to all the time until I just tried:

```
AO: [pulse] Init failed: Connection refused
Failed to initialize audio driver 'pulse'
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pcm_hw.c:1602:(snd_pcm_hw_open) open '/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p' failed (-16): Device or resource busy
[AO_ALSA] alsa-lib: pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
[AO_ALSA] Playback open error: Device or resource busy
Failed to initialize audio driver 'alsa'
[AO SDL] Samplerate: 32000Hz Channels: Stereo Format s16le
[AO SDL] using aalib audio driver.
[AO SDL] Unable to open audio: No available audio device
Failed to initialize audio driver 'sdl:aalib'
Could not open/initialize audio device -> no sound.
Audio: no sound
Video: no video
```

Same for `play`:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
play FAIL formats: can't open output file `default': snd_pcm_open error: Device or resource busy
```

I've tried it as `root` too, same result. **But:** If I run either as the user which is logged into the X session (even over SSH), it works.

Comment: Generally you stream but see https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/playing-audio-files-over-ssh-connection-linux-linux-432640/

Comment: Maybe part of the environment exported from SSH is confusing the players.  E.g. for `mp3blaster`, make sure it has selected the SDL audio driver, and then try forcing SDL to use the right backend with `export SDL_AUDIODRIVER=pulseaudio` or maybe `export SDL_AUDIODRIVER=alsa`

Comment: @l0b0 Please see my edit, I'm not trying to stream.

Comment: Does the `mplayer` output show which audio device it eventually uses?

Comment: @JigglyNaga Just tried it, mplayer doesn't work anymore either. It used to work all the time, that's really weird. Added output to question. I've tried to run it as root too. Same with `play`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue with something rather obvious I missed this whole time. I had to allow **other users** (not the user logged into the X session under which the pulseaudio deamon runs) access to PA.

On the user under which the PA deamon runs:

```
# create pulse config dir in $HOME if it doesn't exist yet
mkdir .pulse
# copy the default PA config file
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa .pulse/default.pa
# edit the file
nano .pulse/default.pa
```

Then add onto the end of the file:

```
# make PA accessible by all users
load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1 socket=/tmp/acpulsesocket
```

Then, logged in as the user from which you want to play audio:

```
# create pulse config dir in $HOME of the controlling user
mkdir .pulse
# create client configuration file
nano .pulse/client.conf
```

And paste the following into the file:

```
default-server = unix:/tmp/acpulsesocket
```

Save, restart pulseaudio: `pulseaudio -k`

Now `cmus` and every other player is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use `mpd` and `ncmpcpp` to achieve the same thing.

Start `mpd` on the server, then use `ncmpcpp -h hostname_of_jukebox` to control it from any other computer on the network.

No need for `ssh` besides starting `mpd` remotely (which can be autostarted as a service/daemon, if you want).

You can use other programs to control `mpd`, as well.

Comment: That looks very cool, but I consider the cmus-over-ssh approach to be simpler, especially when it's a remote location and you don't want to open another port globally.